# javascript know when you're clicking on the first cell of a table row

Tags: javascript

I have a table displaying tabular data in the form of a report.  I am trying to make it so when you click anywhere on the row, it navigates to a more detailed view of that particular item.

**HTML (from PHP)**

```
'<tr onClick="ViewItem(this, '.$ItemNum.')">'.
    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_'.$ItemNum.'" /></td>'.
    '<td>a</td>'.
    '<td>b</td>'.
    '<td>c</td>'.
'</tr>'
```

**Javascript**

```
function ViewItem(elThisRow, ItemNum)
{
    // If first <td> was clicked, return
    // ?

    // Otherwise, navigate to item
    window.location="/viewitem.php?i=" + ItemNum;
}
```

Well the clicking and navigation part works fine, but the only thing is, the first  has a checkbox control there.

So right now, I cannot really use the checkbox because the page will navigate away when I click it :(

Is there any way to figure out which cell was clicked, so I can prevent it from navigating if it's the first cell?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` object gives you a `srcElement` or `target` property (depending on whether you're on IE or not) so you can see what element was clicked and thus ignore clicks on input elements:

```
'<tr onClick="ViewItem(event, this, '.$ItemNum.')">'.

function ViewItem(e, elThisRow, ItemNum) {
     if (!e) e = window.event;
     var target = e.srcElement || e.target;

     if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT")
         return;

     window.location="/viewitem.php?i=" + ItemNum;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LXeqV/

More information about the differences between handling events with IE and with other browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

(Or of course libraries like jQuery do the cross-browser stuff for you.)

Comment: Wow it works like a charm!  Thanks!  Also, I didn't know about the "event" argument.  That's highly useful.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know PHP, but if you would like to use JQuery, it should be much easier.
just bind click event to each td(column), then decide what to do according to the column No.

Comment: Even with jQuery you'd still bind the click to the rows but you'd check the event object's `target` property to see whether it was the checkbox which was clicked.

Comment: Why? can't I bind the click to <td></td> ?

Comment: (I didn't downvote your answer, but) In a general sense it is more efficient to have fewer event handlers. So yes, you certainly can bind to each td, but it is "cleaner" to bind to the rows. (You could even bind just to the table, though personally I wouldn't take it that far.)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer either, but apparently someone downvoted it and my question as well :(  Oh well... can't please everyone :)